# Laravel Valet Operation not Permitted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-valet

I have PHP 7.3 and a Laravel 8 site that has been parked with Laravel Valet.  I try to access the application at app.test and I get the following message:

Warning: opendir(/Users/username/Desktop/CodingProjects): failed to open dir: Operation not permitted in /Users/username/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 132 404 - Not Found

I have tried making the public folder and server.php file executable in the Laravel root folder the app is running it and have been going in circles.  Running a Mac with an M1 chip.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue after I upgraded to Mac OS Ventura.

The steps I used to fix this:

1. `rm -rf ~/.config/valet`
2. `valet install`
3. `valet park` to the main folder for all the sites. You can run `valet link changeToYourDirectory` if you want to link only a single directory.

Comment: was pulling my hair like crazy (￣ ￣|||)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue and managed to solve by the following steps: (Note: you will need to reconfigure your parked directories and linked projects after that)

1. `valet parked` to check the current directories parked
2. `valet links` to check the current projects linked
3. `rm -rf ~/.config/valet` removing valet configurations
4. `valet install` reconfigure valet
5. Repark and relink removed directories and projects